# Unable to call external API from VPN/VPC in Mulesoft

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, cloudhub

I am trying to call an external API using HTTP request from my Mule application. When the Mule application is deployed locally, I am able to access the external API. However, when I deploy the application to cloudhub with VPN/VPC, the call to external API fails with error as TimeOut.

As per my understanding, since I am able to access the external API from my local machine the external API port is open and there is no restriction. I could not figure out what could be the reason it is not working in VPN/VPC.

Also checked the firewall rules in cloudhub and nothing seems to be wrong.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall rules in CloudHub are only for incoming connections. Outgoing connections are not restricted.

VPNs and VPCs are different concepts. Do you mean a VPC (ie a network in a cloud) is connected to your company's networks through a VPN (ie an encrypted communications link)?

If you are able to connect 'locally', which I'll make an educated guess that mean it is from a computer inside your corporate network, it may be because your corporate network is whitelisted at the external API side. Are you connecting from the application deployed to CloudHub through the public Internet or through your company's network? Is there whitelisting? I guess that your VPC is not whitelisted at the external API side.

Comment: Was the answer helpful?